# steps to use Jdatepicker in Jtextfield in Java desktop application

Tags: datepicker, desktop

I downloaded jdatepicker-1.3.2-sources.jar and added to my Library of my project.
when i try to import it , it says package not found. can anyone jot me down the clear steps . I am not using drag and drop in here.
I want the date picker in JTextField

Answer (score 0):

A sources jar doesn't contain the compiled binaries, so your import statements will not work. Sources jar files are provided so that you can browse the source by associating the class files to the sources within your IDE.

You should download the jar with only the artifactid, ie: jdatepicker-1.3.4.jar or use a build tool such as maven / gradle to get the dependencies.

You can download the latest version of JDatePicker from:
https://search.maven.org/#browse%7C812449245

Comment: Here is an example of how to use the JDatePicker widget: https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jdatepicker/TestJDatePicker.java